# Rich Textfield in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm looking into a textfield multiline that could accept an image as a attachment. Something like this. Is there anything available in Material UI that let me do something like that ?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/jpuri/React-draft-wysiwyg (though doesn't seem to support attachments)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610698/how-to-include-attach-file-option-in-react-draft-wysiwyg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box. There are some third party libraries though, that implement rich editors and are compatible with mui like this:
https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte

Comment: Currently, it doesn't work with React ^18.2.0 [issue here](https://github.com/niuware/mui-rte/issues/333)

Answer (score 1):

I released a package recently `mui-tiptap` (https://github.com/sjdemartini/mui-tiptap) which uses the robust and increasingly popular [Tiptap](https://tiptap.dev/) editor under the hood, all styled with MUI's [Material-UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/). It's customizable, uses your own MUI theme (colors, fonts, light vs dark mode, etc.), and includes a lot of functionality out of the box (an all-in-one `RichTextEditor` component, multiple Tiptap extensions, composable/extendable menu buttons, etc.).

You can try it out yourself at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-tiptap-demo-3zl2l6).

[image: mui-tiptap demo]